# How do I make items in same row appear in same row, different columns - skeleton boilerplate

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am just beginning to learn to code. I am using Skeleton boilerplate to build a responsive template. I am struggling to understand, how to make two items appear on the same row. below is my code for this.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container"
        <div class="row">
             <div class="three.columns"><img src="/image/file">
             </div>
        <div class="nine.columns">Headline</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

`

Comment: Have you learned HTML, Javascript before? If not, I suggest you to learn them first before this Complicated Skeleton boilerplate CSS.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, it was worth the try. As i get better, my posts here should improve with quality.

Answer (score 1):

">" is missing from the container div.

This would be the correct code:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="three columns"><img src="/image/file"></div>
      <div class="nine columns">Headline</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```